# Is there a non-obvious in-story significance to the title of “Jane, Unlimited”?

Tags: jane-unlimited

In "Jane, Unlimited," in the typology of alternate universes used (created?) by

> Anita Thrash

a limited dimension (LD) has less paranormal (transnormal, in her words) activity than an unlimited dimension (UD). On the other hand, some people in UD17 seem to think that superstitional and belief in the divine, instead, are indicative of a limited dimension, which seems almost opposite.

Does the use of the word “unlimited” to refer to Jane in the title indicate:

- That the initial dimension (and, presumably, the at least five branching dimensions presented) are indeed unlimited dimensions? And what would that really mean?
- That Jane herself is somehow special in an dimensional sense (LD42’s Anita Thrash did note that she hadn’t seen much of her in other dimensions)?

Or something else altogether, perhaps only a vaguely appropriate title?